# how to use hasMany through laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a problem with laravel orm. I have three tables table A(id,.......),
Table B(id, A_id ,C_id,.....), 
table C(id,....).
and table A and B has one to many relation and 
table B and C have one to one relation. 
How can I use hasMany on C from table A. Like

```
class aModel {
function b(){
return hasMany(app\Models\bModel');
}
// i want to do this
function c(){
return hasMany('App\Models\cModel');
}
}
class bModel{
function a(){
return belongsTo('App\Models\aModel);
}
function c(){
return belngsTo('App\Models\cModel');
}
}
like aModel::with(['b'])->get(); i want.
$a = aModel::with( ['c] )->get();
```

anyone please................

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `hasManyThrough()` method.

```
return hasManyThrough('App\Models\cModel', 'App\Models\bModel');
```

Answer (score 0):

oh actually its little tricky.. i found my solution..

solutin is 
aModel::where(['b.c'])->get();

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`hasManyThrough()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through):

```
public function cModels()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Models\cModel', 'App\Models\bModel');
}
```

Or you can just use [nested eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading):

```
aModel::with('bModels.cModels')->get();
```

Comment: Don't forget to use `Model::class` instead of `App\Models\Model` string :-)